# Bean not in the JNDI

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss, jndi

I created a small web service(test), I'm unable to get it to deploy to jboss server. It might be something with one of these files, this is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/testing/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

here is servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />

</beans:beans>
```

And controllers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- This required so that Spring can recognize our annotated beans -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.jd" />

</beans>
```

I can't figure out what seems to be the problem(I think the code is not the problem, I might be wrong). any ideas?

**Sorry forgot to mention this(big one) :**

Here is the exception -> http://pastebin.com/m1aQFmbj

Fixed it **

`@Resource(mappedName="userService", name="userService")` in addition to name added, mappedName.

Now I've got another one :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userService' is defined: not found in JNDI environment
```

I've tried adding `<bean id="userService" name="userService" class="com.test.jd.service.impl.UserServiceImpl"/>` 
to both controllers and root-context and get this same error.

any clues what to do next(I'm wondering why do I need JNDI)?

Comment: ...and what is going wrong? Other than "it doesn't start"

Comment: See the error message might be helpful.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler @duffymo sorry updated the question. tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JBoss is trying to inject a resource (probably an EJB?) into a servlet or filter. The annotation has a name field with the value 'userService'. JBoss has been unable to find an appropriate resource to inject and is asking for you to specify where the resource exists in JNDI via the 'mappedName' attribute.

This can happen if the name on your EJB and the name of the resource injection don't match. For example the following won't work:

On the EJB: `@Stateless(name="foo")`
In the Servlet: `@EJB(name="bar") private MyBean myBean`

Both name values must be the same.

More information:

- http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html
- http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/injection/

Comment: @johnstok thanks for the swift response, I've checked whether the names match, here is what I don't understand in my service implementation class I got `@Service("userService") @Transactional` , and in my controller `@Resource(name="userService") private UserService userService` exactly the problem you described, but the names are identical both userService

Comment: Your next step is probably to use the JNDIView JMXBean available via the jmx-console to see where the class annotated with @Service has been mounted in JNDI. Try using that path as the mappedName and see if it works. Also, check the JBoss documentation to see how the Resource annotation's name value is mapped into JNDI.

Comment: @johnstok sorry to bother you, it appears not to be in there http://i53.tinypic.com/33vki7l.jpg

Comment: Click the 'Invoke' button for the 'list' operation. ;-)

Comment: @johnstok I updated question, different problem now, if you can take a look that be great

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so familiar with Spring. It's likely Spring is also failing to find the Service in the JNDI location it expects. What's the full path to the Service in JNDI?

Comment: @johnstok it doesn't exist in JNDI as I can see from the instructions you provided

Comment: The @Resource annotation is designed to inject an object stored in JNDI. Could you attach the output of your JNDIView? Also, check the service has been started correctly - there should be an entry in the jmx-console along the lines of `jboss.j2ee:service=EJB3,name=com.test.jd.service.impl.UserServiceImpl,type=service`

Comment: @johnstok here is the output of JNDIView http://pastebin.com/0xSB6JRW, no the service is not started because this error occurs and it cannot be deployed. I updated a question.